# Showing a DialogFragment in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm currently working on converting an Activity into a Fragment. The activity contains a Edittext that when clicked shows a DialogFragmment for picking a date. In the Activity I would simply call this to show the dialog:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(datePickerEditText);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work to show the dialog from a Fragment. I'm getting an error on the "show" method. So to be clear I was wondering how to show a DialogFragment from a Fragment?

This is the code for the DialogFragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

public EditText activity_edittext;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public DatePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
    activity_edittext = edit_text;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(day ) + "/" +   String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed an example using your code, changing the inheritance relationship to FragmentActivity and works fine. Try this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.activity_edittext);
    editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

}

public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(editText);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

The layout used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/activity_edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code work for me, no error on *show* method. Check whether import correct libraries (for example android.support.v4.app.* if you use Support Library).

EDIT - full source code:

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.viduka.stackoverflow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.container, new AFragment());
    ft.commit();
    }
}
```

AFragment.java - from which DatePickerFragment is called

```
package com.viduka.stackoverflow;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public  class AFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        showDatePickerDialog(new EditText(getActivity()));
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(new EditText(getActivity()));
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
}
```

DatePickerFragment.java

```
package com.viduka.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Calendar;    
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public EditText activity_edittext;

    public DatePickerFragment(EditText edit_text) {
        activity_edittext = edit_text;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        activity_edittext.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
    }
}
```